# Coordinate background colour using Print composer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, printing, mapping

How to add coordinate background in Print composer? 
Example in attached picture with coordinates, which is not quite visible.

[image: example]

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not, afaik. You must consider locating them outside the frame

Comment: A work around would be to add a point table with no style and a column controlling the rotation. In label settings under placement you can databind to the rotation column.

Comment: Another workaround would be to add a text box with a background on top of each coordinate.

Comment: Text box on each coordinate is good, when there is one map. In case with plenty of maps, its not quite productive:)